# Как преобразовать черно-белое изображение в матрицу в C++?

Tags: c++, изображения, visual-studio-code, матрицы

Допустим имеется изображение .bmp
Возможно ли представить это изображение в виде матрицы(допустим картинка 20х20 пикселей, значит матрица будет той же размерности), используя какие-нибудь функции из базовых библиотек(т.е. не прибегая к помощи всяких Clmg, OpenCv и тд, которые необходимо дополнительно устанавливать)
Просто считать информацию о количестве пикселей в черно-белом изображении и создать матрицу на основе получившихся значений
И присвоить черному и белому пикселю значение 0 и 1 соответственно...
чтобы получившаяся матрица выглядела примерно так
0000100
0001000
0010000
0001000
0000100

Comment: Можно ли вам пользоваться библиотеками?

Comment: Можно! Но скачивать какие либо дополнительные проблематично и долго, к сожалению... Да и задача не настолько сложная, чтобы пользоваться продвинутыми библиотеками

Comment: Задача сложная, потому что у формата BMP есть несколько вариантов внутренней структуры, и если надо поддерживать их все - вы замахаетесь все это прописывать.

Comment: Вот что удалось найти в интернете первой ссылкой: [ссылка](https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread2400630.html)

Comment: Есть замечательная библиотека, [`stb_image`](https://github.com/nothings/stb) - все в одном хедере, умеет читать десяток самых популярных форматов изображений.